# AppleScript: How to Change the value of a website option menu?

Tags: javascript, applescript

I'm trying to change the value of an option menu of a website via AppleScript.

When I run:

```
tell application "Safari"
 activate
  tell current tab of window 1
   set changeValue to do JavaScript "document.getElementById('selected-ID').innerHTML;"
   return changeValue
  end tell
end tell
```

I get as result:

```
<option value=\"1\">blabla1</option>
<option selected=\"\" value=\"2\">blabla2</option>
<option value=\"3\">blabla3</option>
```

Now I want to change the selected option to be value1.

Can someone please help me. 
I'm getting really frustrated that nothing works

Thank you

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute javascript to change the value of the select element. You should set it to the string of a "value" parameter in one of the select options.

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell current tab of window 1
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('selected-ID').value = '1';"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: That helped me so much!! Thank you!!